# Yo App breakpoint set but is ignored by the IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, breakpoints, corda

I want to set a breakpoint in Intellij for the Yo app.  The nodeA is being started with the following command:

```
cd ../yo-cordapp/build/nodes/PartyA
java -Dcapsule.jvm.args="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5006" -jar corda.jar &
```

As the node starts up from the command line, the message "**Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5006**" is displayed, and in the IDE, clicking **Run** -> **Attach to Local Process** displays "**30988 net.corda.node.Corda(:5006)**" which when selected displays "**Connected to the target VM, address: ':5006', transport: 'socket'**" in the IDE console window.  In Yo.kt, a breakpoint is set at:

```
line 61 "fun me() = mapOf("me" to rpcOps.nodeInfo().legalIdentities.first().name)".
```

I now expect that running "http://localhost:10007/api/yo/me" in Chrome should cause the breakpoint to be hit. But that doesn't happen. Instead, the expected node name string is returned to the browser and there no activity in the IDE debug window.

Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The node's webserver runs in a separate Java process. By attaching the debugger in that way, you're attaching to the Java process of the node itself.

I'm not aware of a way to attach a debugger to the webserver.

Comment: After Yo.kt (or any class with GET and Path annotations) is compiled, does the class get packaged into the webserver java process (e.g. corda-webserver.jar)?